# Listing symbols of library

Tags: gnu, libtool

For `.so` I use `nm -gC`, for `.a` I use just `nm`. What should I use for `.la`?

Comment: Those are not library files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.la` files are only auxiliary files used by `libtool`, so they contain no executable code and no symbols.